# Inserting text manually in Powerquery

Tags: powerquery

I'm merging multiple Excel files into one where the user can review and mark an additional Comment column as completed. Each day there are additional files and I need to refresh the query and pull the data in. Keeping the original Comment column values.

I've attempted to do this by referencing Marcel Beug's [video](https://youtu.be/duNYHfvP_8U) but that uses an sql table and I cannot seem to get it to work with the Excel files as the source.

After the Merge Queries I attempt to modify the first file to my source "InputFile"

```
![Modify the Merge Formula1][2]
![Changed to last query step of InputFile][3]
![InputFile Query with Source2 and Merge][4]
![M Code of InputFile Query with Merge][5]
```

By setting the First field in the Merge Formula to the last step in the InputFile query I was able to get around the Cyclic error however I find that every Refresh creates duplicate rows. 4 become 8 that then becomes 16, etc.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("S:\Fin_Aid\Operations Team\COD mpn - lec\InputFiles\8.22.18 to 8.23.18.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    Rename_RecID = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column3.1", "RecID"}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="InputFile"]}[Content],
    InputWithComment = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"RecID", Int64.Type}, {"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Comment", type text}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Rename_RecID,{"RecID"},InputWithComment,{"RecID"},"InputWithComment",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded InputWithComment" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "InputWithComment", {"Comment"}, {"Comment"})

in
    #"Expanded InputWithComment"
```

Regards,
Jim

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to include your existing code, and links to any relevant research you've done, such as the video to which you refer.

Comment: It can definitely be done with any source of data. I would recommend you post the code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: It doesn't look like any of my screenshots are showing... only the text I attached to them.

Comment: Not sure what's going on there, but you can also go into the "Advanced Editor" in your Query and copy and paste the text from there into a code block. Though knowing what the data looks like will help as well.

Comment: You said you are merging multiple excel files into one? The query you posted is only using a single file. I think the issue may be you are trying to do this at the wrong point. You would want to apply Marcel's tutorial only to the final query where you are combining all of your Excel sheets and loading them into the workbook.